# jQuery: quickest way to determine if at least one child in a container is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, visible

What is the quickest way to determine if at least one child `div` in a `div` container is visible?

I've been using this:

`if ($this.children('div:visible').length) {...`

but it's slow because it examines all the children (of which there are a lot).

I'm guessing the fastest method will stop searching as soon as it's found the first visible element, but whatever is fastest wins :)

BTW:

> My actual situation is a major container which contains about 100
>   minor containers, each of which contain up to 100 elements. I want to
>   determine which minor containers have at least one visible element.
>   The elements at the bottom are being hidden and shown by various
>   classes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### JSPerf of all methods on this page

- All elements visible: http://jsperf.com/jquery-quickest-visible-check/3
- All elements hidden: http://jsperf.com/jquery-quickest-visible-check/2
  The suggested alternative using `.each()` and `.is(':visible')` is the slowest method. My/[qwertymk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11412765/938089)'s method turns out to be faster than the OPs solution, in the case that all elements are visible. However, when all elements are hidden, the **original method seems to be optimal**.

**Edited:** The reason that my original method is faster is that it used `.find('>' + selector)`, where `.children()` has to be used (which loops through all children, and checks whether the element matches a selector).

Since `div` is a natively supported selector, and the test case does not contain deeply nested elements, my solution turned out to be fast. But after normalizing it, it looks almost equal to qwertymks solution. The JSPerf of these two solutions will show that his solution is slightly faster, because it has one less function call.

The solutions on this page are generic: The code below can be optimized for specific cases (such as the fact that the selector is just a tag): http://jsfiddle.net/kFZJs/

---

To speed up the progress, split up the selector, because `:visible` is not a native CSS selector.

The preferred solution should use as few jQuery as possible, because the desired solution has to be performant. To do so, [examine the logic of `:visible`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9638017/938089?non-jquery-equivalent-of-visible-in-javascript).

The original function contains `jQuery.support.reliableHiddenOffsets`. This can safely be stripped in favour of performance when your childs are not table cells (which is only used in IE8-).

Now, write a jQuery plugin (it's not expensive):

```
 (function($) {
     $.fn.hasAtLeastOneVisibleChild = function(selector) {
         var $col = this.children(selector), i, elem;
         for (i=0; i<$col.length; i++) {
             var elem = $col[i];
             if (elem.offsetWidth !== 0 || elem.offsetHeight !== 0) {
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
     };
 })(jQuery);
 // Usage:
 $this.hasAtLeastOneVisibleChild('div'); // True or false
```

Comment: `$elem` is misleading, it should be `elem` but still gets a +1

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying to implement your solution, but I've hit a snag. Here's the code to test the actual problem.         `$('#clf').children('ul').each(function (i) {var $that = $(this);$that.children().each(function (){if ($(this).hasAtLeastOneVisibleChild('li')) {console.log("Found one for " + $that.attr('id'));} else {console.log("Found none for " + $that.attr('id'));}});});`  I'm getting multiple console.logs for each `ul`, though (13, 17...). Can you see why?

Comment: @Nick Once you find a match, you have to break out of the loop using `return false;`. See also docs: http://api.jquery.com/each/.

Comment: @qwertymk Thanks for the spot, I've edited that part, as well as included the JSPerf test.

Comment: That sorted it. Thanks again. The JSPerf is pretty convincing :)

Comment: BTW - my test code 4 comments back has an extra .each loop that messes things up.

Comment: @Nick I've reviewed and edited my answer. Now, the conclusions are quite different: In the case that most/all elements are visible, my solution is the best one. In the case that all elements are hidden, your original method is slightly better. RE: Your code: It contains `$().children('ul').each()` In the each loop, you're using `$that.children().each` and `.hasAtLeastOneVisibleChild('li')`. `$that.children()` is already a collection of `<li>`, they won't have `<li>` childs.

Comment: Yes, Rob, I spotted the extra `$that.children().each`. I was also persevering with your original `===` elem checks before you changed it to `!==`, but I worked out why it wasn't working and then noticed you'd changed it! Thanks again for your help. Also, the maths doesn't quite add up: +1 from Adil, qwertymk & me should make more than +2 :)

Comment: FYI, Rob. I tested a local function and the omission of the selector (which is unnecessary for me) at http://jsperf.com/jquery-quickest-visible-check/4. I'd be interested to know the theoretical performance differences between having a $.fn and a local function if you understand such matters :)

Comment: @Nick That's worth a new question. The difference is caused by Prototype chain vs scope chain lookups. The latter is faster than the former: http://jsperf.com/scope-chain-vs-prototype-chain-lookup. Do not put function declarations in a loop though: Creating functions is not free.

Comment: Very different results from Safari, Chrome & Firefox. Safari seems not to punish the local function creation whereas Firefox hammers it.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to iterate through children by using [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). But this will be as slow as your code if the visible element is the last one :)

Another option would be to check the height of the container.

```
if($('#container').height() > 0) { ... }
```

If the children takes space (height), then the container will have height > 0 as well.

Comment: What if the children are absolutely positioned? Then the check would not be reliable.

Comment: That's right. It will not work in every case, but might work in his case :) And if works in his case it will be VERY fast

Comment: I +1ed because it's indeed fast (reliable if the exact conditions are known beforehand and satisfied). I did not include your code in my test case though, because it's not comparable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Use each for iterating and returning false on match could decrease the iteration could.

```
isAtleastVisible = false;
$this.children('div').each(function (){
    if($(this).is(':visible') == true)
    {
       isAtleastVisible = true;
       return false;  //This will break each loop at the first visible div
    }
});

if(isAtleastVisible)
   alert("atleast one is visible");
else
   alert("None is visible");
```

This will increase the performance and it depends on the the first occurrence of visible div. If it is first one out of hundred only one iteration will be required and if it is hundredth out of hundred then hundred iteration will be required and there will not be any performance increase.

As *@Rob W* explained in answer about the working of is('visible') which shows the function checks the visibility by these parameters.

1. Width and height is zero
2. style.display is none

You can use one of these to increase performance suppose the elements are hidden by setting display = none. This condition could replace jQuery method .is(':visible') == true with javascript statement .style.display == 'block'

```
    isAtleastVisible = false;
    $this.children('div').each(function (){
        if(this.style.display == 'block')
        {
           isAtleastVisible = true;
           return false;  //This will break each loop at the first visible div
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is the only incorrect solution on this page. `.is('visible')` checks whether the selected item is a `<visible>` element. The correct implementation of `.is()` is posted under [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11412732/938089) (although it contains an obsolete double jQuery-wrapping: `$($(...))`).

Comment: Thanks @Rob W, I have tried to improve my answer please have a look.

Comment: The suggestion is not necessary going to work: `style.display` may be `""` (and still visible) or the parent might be hidden. The suggestion is very specific: It does not account for `display:table-cell;`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Do it youself:

```
var $container = $('#container'), $children = $container.children(), found = false;

for (var i = 0; i < $container.length; i++) {
    var elem = $children[i];
    if (!( width === 0 && height === 0 ) || (!jQuery.support.reliableHiddenOffsets && ((elem.style && elem.style.display) || jQuery.css( elem, "display" )) === "none")){
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

### [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L582)

Comment: `return` inside a loop? Did you mean `break`?

Comment: Your code is not limited to `div`s. I'm creating a JSPerf to test all methods. I'm replacing `.children()` with `.children('div')`, to make the comparison equal. EDIT: `width` and `height` are not defined, throws an error in the test case.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm working with Rob's effort but this was valiant too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var isVisible;
$(this.children('div')).each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
        isVisible = true;
        return false;
    }
});
```