# Emulating jQuery :visible selector with plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, chocolatechip-ui

I am converting a piece of code from jQuery to [ChocolateChip UI](http://chocolatechip-ui.com/), and this piece of code is stumping me as ChocolateChip UI doesn't support ':visible' for its implementation of `is()`

```
if (interactive && block.is(':visible')) {
            block.fadeOut(250, function() {
                block.html(newContent);
                block.fadeIn(750);
            });
            showHighlight($("#character_text"));
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute query: ':visible' is not a valid selector.
```

Two questions:

1. How can I emulate `is(':visible')` using plain JavaScript?
2. How can I extend ChocolateChip UI's `is()` to handle `:visible`?

Comment: if(document.getElementById("elementId").style.visibility=="visible"){
    // do something
    }

Comment: I assume that doesn't work because `:visible` is an extension by jQuery. So you might run into the same issue with other selectors. jQuery actually does a couple of things to determine whether an element is visible, which is explained in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/.

Comment: @AdnanK: That is not sufficient. The element might be styled through stylesheets and it might not have the `visibility` rule set but is visible nonetheless.

Comment: *"In jQuery 1.3.2 an element is visible if its browser-reported offsetWidth or offsetHeight is greater than 0"*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [non-jQuery equivalent of :visible in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637943/non-jquery-equivalent-of-visible-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an answer to your second question :

ChocolateChip UI does not seem to offer a way to extend selectors. The [code for the `.is()` function](https://github.com/sourcebitsllc/chocolatechip-ui/blob/fe34d214bb60b2a2224a344f03faad9510ce2cd4/src/chocolatechip/collection.js#L66) shows that, when the selector is a string, this string is directly fed to `.querySelectorAll()`.

However, you can also pass a `function` as an argument, so using the predicate [Pieter de Bie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20281040/86072) pointed out, you can write :

```
$.fn.extend({
   isVisible: function(){
       return this.is( function(elem){
           return elem.offsetWidth > 0 || elem.offsetHeight > 0;
       });
   }
});

if ( $('.mySelector').isVisible() ){
    ....
}
```

---

Another solution is to use jQuery : the authors stipulate that their library should be compatible with jQuery > 2.0.3 (see [the project's Readme](https://github.com/sourcebitsllc/chocolatechip-ui/tree/fe34d214bb60b2a2224a344f03faad9510ce2cd4#chocolatechip-ui)).

Answer (score 11):

As an answer on your first question:

> In jQuery 1.3.2 an element is visible if its browser-reported offsetWidth or offsetHeight is greater than 0.
>   ([source](http://blog.jquery.com/2009/02/20/jquery-1-3-2-released/#%3avisible.2F%3ahidden_Overhauled))

So

```
$(element).is(":visible")
```

Should be the same as

```
(element.offsetWidth > 0 || element.offsetHeight > 0)
```

Comment: Be aware this works exactly like jQuery, therefore `"Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout."`