# How do I auto play my slideshow

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I'm really new to everything from Javascript to HTML. Literally not good at it yet, just copying some code from the net and using it as my project.
not really hosting it or anything.
This is a full CSS image slider. so literally my code is just that but different pics, I'm wondering how do I make the images auto play?
so this is it in jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/z269hj0a/

```
<ul class="slides">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8504/8365873811_d32571df3d_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8068/8250438572_d1a5917072_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8061/8237246833_54d8fa37f0_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8055/8098750623_66292a35c0_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-dots">
      <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
      <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
      <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
      <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
      <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
      <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);

html, body { background: #333 url("http://codepen.io/images/classy_fabric.png"); }

.slides {
    padding: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    transform: scale(0);

    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

      opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: opacity .2s;

    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 380px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
    top: -5px;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code in one question. Consider using http://jsfiddle.net to add all your code so that people can take a look.

Comment: @ClizzyJ You can edit your question.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Already placed it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is call the click event on your `.next` class that is currently visible. To do this automatically you would use JavaScript, for example, place this in a `setInterval()` that activates every 5 seconds:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(".next:visible").click();
}, 5000);
```

*Note* This uses jQuery, there is a [equivalent for visible in pure JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637943/non-jquery-equivalent-of-visible-in-javascript), but is a bit messy.

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/z269hj0a/1/)

Comment: Actually nvm i got it to work LOL AND THANKS SO MUCH SPENCER :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you you can do it without jQuery, and you can stop and resume autoplay on hover, as in my example:

**carousel.js**

```
var interval;

fnAutoSlide();

document.getElementById("element_slides").onmouseover = function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

document.getElementById("element_slides").onmouseout = function() {
    fnAutoSlide();
}

function fnAutoSlide() {
    interval = setInterval(
    function()
    {
        var nextSlideClick = document.getElementsByClassName('next'), i;

        for (var i = 0; i < nextSlideClick.length; i ++) {
        if (window.getComputedStyle(nextSlideClick[i], null).display != "none") {
                nextSlideClick[i].click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }, 4000);
}
```

- don't forget to set your ul class "slides" an id: "element_slides".