# How can I make this slidshow autoplay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow, slide

I have this slider that can change background pic by clicking buttons, but I don't know how to make it play automatically... I am not familiar with Javascript or Jquery, so I couldn't figure it out. Can anyone please help? Many thanks!

HTML

```
<div id="full-slide" class="slider">
  <ul class="banner fadein">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <i class="las la-angle-left prev"></i><i class="las la-angle-right next"></i>
</div>
```

```
li
   &active
    opacity: 1
    transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out

li:nth-child(1)
    background-image: url('1.jpg')      
    .
    .           
li:nth-child(4)
    background-image: url('4.jpg')
```

JS

```
function fullSlider(){

    $('#full-slide .prev, #full-slide .next').click(function(){

        var $this = $(this),
                current = $('.banner').find('.active'),
                position = $('.banner').children().index(current),
                totalPics = $('.banner').children().length; 

        if ($this.hasClass('next')){

            if (position < totalPics - 1){
                $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            }

            else {  
                $('.banner li').removeClass('active').first().addClass('active');
            }

        }

        else {

            if (position === 0){
                $('.banner li').removeClass('active').last().addClass('active');
            }

            else {
                $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I auto play my slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407291/how-do-i-auto-play-my-slideshow)

Comment: It does!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This helped me a lot in creating a slideshow: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp

 You don't really need to use jQuery to make an automatic or manual slideshow, although of course is is possible.

Comment: Will look into it. Thank you:)

Comment: No worries, hope that it is useful for you :)